# Uniqueness of Vector Space Structure Given Linearity of Lifted Diffeomorphisms

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

[I have revised and reposted this question here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4720992/1085417)

Let $\mathcal{M}$ be a finite-dimensional smooth manifold. Let $S(\mathcal{M})$ be the set of all smooth real-valued functions, $f:\mathcal{M}\to\mathbb{R}$. For any $f\in S(\mathcal{M})$ and any diffeomorphism, $d\in\text{Diff}(\mathcal{M})$, let $d^*f:=f\circ d^{-1}$ be the lifted action of $d$ on $S(\mathcal{M})$. Finally, let $V_\text{p}(\mathcal{M}):=(S(\mathcal{M}),+_\text{p},\cdot_\text{p})$ be the vector space of smooth functions on $\mathcal{M}$ where $+_\text{p}$ and $\cdot_\text{p}$ are the point-wise addition and scalar multiplication operations on $\mathcal{M}$. (Edit: As Wofsey rightly notes below, we could alternately have here any pointwise operations, $\oplus_\text{p}$ and $\odot_\text{p}$, for any vector space structure $(\mathbb{R},\oplus,\odot)$ for $\mathbb{R}$.)

One can easily show that for any diffeomorphism, $d:\mathcal{M}\to\mathcal{M}$, its lifted action, $d^*:S(\mathcal{M})\to S(\mathcal{M})$, is linear with respect to $V_\text{p}(\mathcal{M})$. Namely, it distributes over $+_\text{p}$ and $\cdot_\text{p}$ as follows:

$d^*(\alpha \cdot_\text{p} f +_\text{p} \beta \cdot_\text{p} g)=\alpha \cdot_\text{p} d^*f +_\text{p} \beta \cdot_\text{p} d^*g$

for all $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{R}$ and all $f,g\in S(\mathcal{M})$. (Edit: Again, as Wofsey notes this holds true also for every point-wise operation $\oplus_\text{p}$ and $\odot_\text{p}$.)

My original question was as follows: Could there be some other vector space structure $V_\text{alt}(\mathcal{M}):=(S(\mathcal{M}),+_\text{alt},\cdot_\text{alt})$ for $S(\mathcal{M})$ such that every $d^*$ is linear with respect to $V_\text{alt}(\mathcal{M})$ as well as $V_\text{p}(\mathcal{M})$?

As Wofsey correctly notes below, we could here have $V_\text{alt}(\mathcal{M})=(S(\mathcal{M}),\oplus_\text{p},\odot_\text{p})$ for any of the point-wise operations mentioned above, $\oplus_\text{p}$ and $\odot_\text{p}$. My revised question is, could there be some vector space structure $V_\text{alt}(\mathcal{M})$ other than these? Namely, given that every $d^*$ is linear, could the vector space structure be anything other than pointwise?

Comment: Phrased differently, my question is about the following scenario. Suppose that your friend has in mind some vector space structure $V$(M)=($S$(M),+,$\cdot$) for $S$(M) but she refuses to tell you what the + and $\cdot$ operations are. You set out to ask her whether each d* maps is linear w.r.t. $V$(M) and she says yes every time. Knowing that d* is linear w.r.t. $V_p$(M) we gain some partial evidence that she is thinking of $V$(M)=$V_p$(M). This, however, is not yet guaranteed since these d* maps might also be linear w.r.t. some other structure $V_{alt}$(M).

Comment: Maybe you want slightly stronger hypotheses to exclude some trivial cases?  It certainly is possible to have another such vector space structure if $M$ is a single point (so the only $d^*$ is the identity map).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the maps $d^*$ more generally preserve *any* pointwise-defined operations.  So, they will preserve any vector space structure that is defined pointwise, not necessarily by the standard operations.  That is, let $\oplus,\odot$ be the addition and scalar multiplications of *any* $\mathbb{R}$-vector space structure on the set $\mathbb{R}$.  Then $S(M)$ becomes an $\mathbb{R}$-vector space with operations $\oplus_p$ and $\odot_p$ defined by $(f\oplus_p g)(x)=f(x)\oplus g(x)$ and $(c\odot_p f)(x)=c\odot f(x)$.  For any diffeomorphism $d:M\to M$, $d^*:S(M)\to S(M)$ is then linear with respect to these operations.

Comment: Perfect answer, thank you. I have revised my question to ask if there are any vector space structures other than these. Also, I think that the case which I am actually interested in has some smooth topology constraints going on in the background. I think these might restrict us back to the standard $+$ and $\cdot$ operations. I'll have to look into this.